# How can I write a for loop that writes a code template to file in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, ranged-loops

I was wondering if there is a way to write a template to file inside of a for loop. The code below is an example of what I have written so far. The variable inside of the open function equals 'python.py'.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    x = 0
    for x in range(5):
        fout.write(""" def function_number{}(): \n
""".format(x))
```

Here is what I am expecting to happen

```
def function_number0():

def function_number1():

def function_number2():

def function_number3():

def function_number4():
```

Here is the output I receive

```
def function_number0():

            def function_number1():

            def function_number2():

            def function_number3():

            def function_number4():
```

How can I restructure my code to get the desired output?

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this–I get the expected (unindented, with no parentheses after the numbers) output when running the above code (python 3.5.2). Are you sure you're running the right program and that you're reading the correct output file?

Comment: Allow me to edit the question. There should have been parentheses after the numbers, but before the colon.

Comment: Were there supposed to be parentheses in the `fout.write` call in the code you posted? It doesn't seem like the output you're receiving is being generated from the code in the post.

Comment: There were supposed to be parentheses there as well.

Comment: Okay. I still get the expected output (test with 3.7 this time). Here's a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/n19SMhp.png

Could you double-check that you're running the right program and reading the correct output file?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/4dUd854.png) Here is a screenshot of my terminal output. Pico is the name of the command line utility that I have written that contains the code with the for loop inside. It creates the file python.py inside of the folder the script resides in. There is no other file with that name in the directory. I even make sure to delete the output and re-run the program again.

Would this be a problem on MacOS? That is my current OS. I am also using VSCode as my text editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176906/discussion-between-ollin-boer-bohan-and-bradleygamimarques).